# Java Spring Web Serialize properties of child class

Tags: java, spring, rest, inheritance

I have a Maven Java Spring Rest project where I want to do this.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {
  @GetMapping
  public List<Person> getPerson(){

    List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

    persons.add(new Dev(1, "Java")); //Let's say I have the constructor
    persons.add(new DevOps(2, "Linux")); //Let's say I have the constructor

    return implants;
  }
}

  public class Person{ public int id;}

  public class Dev extends Person{ public string lang;}

  public class DevOps extends Person{ public string env;}
```

And I want the result to be

[

{id : 1, lang: "Java"}, //<- this is the Dev

{id : 2, env: "Linux"}, //<- this is the DevOps

]

And not just

[

{id : 1}, //<- this is the Dev

{id : 2}, //<- this is the DevOps

]

Comment: Post your class constructors as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to reproduce your issue and was not successful:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<Person> getPerson(){
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        persons.add(new Dev(1, "Java")); //Let's say I have the constructor
        persons.add(new DevOps(2, "Linux")); //Let's

        return persons;
    }
}

public class Person {
    public int id;

    public Person(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Dev extends Person {
    public String lang;

    public Dev(int id, String lang) {
        super(id);
        this.lang = lang;
    }
}

public class DevOps extends Person {
    public String env;

    public DevOps(int id, String env) {
        super(id);
        this.env = env;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
http://localhost:8080/person/

[{"id":1,"lang":"Java"},{"id":2,"env":"Linux"}]
```

Are you sure you posted all the relevant code? Since you stated `Let's say I have the constructor`, I can only assume you created them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, in my real life exemple the proprieties were private and I forgot to create the getter.